# MediaPlayer.TrackInfo[i].getLanguage() in Android is always returning "und"

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I do not know if this is a bug in Android or if I am missing something here, but I can never get the actual language code of a given audio track with this MediaPlayer method:

```
MediaPlayer.TrackInfo[] mediaplayerTrackInfoArray = myMediaPlayer.getTrackInfo();

String a_string = mediaplayerTrackInfoArray[index].getLanguage(); // index must indicate the position of an actual audio track
```

All I always get is the `String: "und"`, which supposedly means: *undetermined*.

I know that the video file being analyzed does contain the audio tracks with their respective language codes, for example: "eng" or "rus", because they show up correctly in an external media player like VLC.

Is there a fix to this bug? Or a substitute method or object?

Comment: Please provide a `MWE` (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help others understand your issue.

Comment: @Carlos Botero Have you  Solve this issue?

Comment: Hola (Hello). Greetings. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to solve the problem. Check if Google and/or official android creators have solved the issue. I am seriously thinking of switching to a better media player, like ExoPlayer for Android. Cheers. Saludos